# clean REST routes

Tags: node.js, rest, url-routing

i´m not sure about my REST naming.

I have 3 routes:

**GET** and **DELETE** and **PUT** */book/:bookId/translation/:translationId*

With **GET** I get the translation of a book. With **DELETE** I delete the translation of one book. And with **PUT** I change the translation.

But how about the naming for the **POST** route?
With **POST** I will create a new translation for a book.

Should it better be */book/:bookId* or */book/:bookId/translation*

Thanks´s a lot for your feedback!

Comment: Are you posting to the book of that ID or are you posting to the translation at that ID? And does that even make sense to do so?

Comment: We need to know a lot more about what the POST is actually doing in order to comment on the naming of the route.

Comment: Okay sorry, I will update my post!

Comment: Given your new explanation, I would think you would want the POST to be `/book/:bookId/translation` to specify that you are creating a new translation for a specific book and bookId and that is consistent with how you are using GET and DELETE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should it better be /book/:bookId or /book/:bookId/translation

It seems that `/book/:bookId/translation` would make the most sense for the POST of a new translation for the following reasons:

1. You are properly specifying what you are posting (a translation to a specific book id).
2. This is consistent with how you query a translation with `/book/:bookId/translation/:translationId`.
3. It would be consistent with how you would query a list of translations by doing a GET on `/book/:bookId/translation`.
4. This overall scheme makes sense in that it is what type of object, followed by an object id, followed by what type of sub-object.